# send/recive between PC and Inverter using python Socket programming

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I able to send data but can not receive. Can I request to check my coding ?

```py
import socket

def Main():
    
    HOSTPC = '192.168.140.22' # host PC
    port = 51965 
    address = (HOSTPC,port)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    c = ('192.168.42.180',502) # SMA inverter with MODBUS activate 
    s.connect (c)
    s.sendto(b'03049d030002',c) # Modbus register value (data is 32bit) 
    print("sent") # output is showing sent that means sending data
    data = s.recv(1024) # 
    print(data)         # I am not reciving any data ???
    s.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: what exactly is the mistake? throws an error when trying to receive data? or is it just stuck on this block of code ```data = s.recv(1024) # ```?

Comment: `sendto` does ot make any sense with a connected socket (and TCP sockets must be connected). Use `send` instead.

Comment: what exactly is the mistake? throws an error when trying to receive data? or is it just stuck on this block of code data = s.recv(1024) # ? – crackanddie 17 hours ago
- Yes,  it just stuck on this block of code data = s.recv(1024).